# Change Navigation View Item Color Dynamically Android

Tags: android, drawerlayout, androiddesignsupport, navigationview

I'd like to build a navigation drawer where each item has a different selection color (the icon tint and text color) as the google play store has:

[image]

I'm not sure how they've solved this, I think they use different activities with different drawers. I want to use fragments and I want to change the icon tint and text color. Any ideas how I can do this? I'm using google's design support library and a drawer layout with a navigation view in there.

Comment: It's possible they didn't use the NavigationView, since this was in the app way before the design support library (if I recall correctly). I think you have the recreate the view yourself to achieve this effect.

Comment: @tom. did you get a solution, you seemed to have accepted the answer but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

use `app:itemIconTint` in your `NavigationView` for icons and use `app:itemTextColor` for textColors

**Sample :**

`drawable/navigation_text_color` :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- This is used when the Navigation Item is checked -->
    <item android:color="#009688" android:state_checked="true" />
    <!-- This is the default text color -->
    <item android:color="#E91E63" />
</selector>
```

and `layout` :

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
       .
       .
       app:itemTextColor="@drawable/navigation_text_color"/>
```

Comment: thanks, I'm now changing the ColorStateList each time a menu item has been clicked.

Comment: Where would you put this selector XML snippet? Also, `app:itemTextColor` changes the color of all the icons. Is there a way to change just one icon's color? Thanks!

Comment: @justinrixx I'm changing it every time an item is selected with the following java code: https://jsfiddle.net/a2j7jayo/

Comment: @justinrixx no, in material design concepts, in navigation view, all icons must be one color

Comment: @D.A.V.O.O.D so u don't use inbox for example ? Some icons has different colors even if they are not the "checked" one. I think that's what justinrixx want to achieve (and so do i).

Comment: has anyone got the answer to this? i am facing the same issue?

Comment: @ParthAnjaria what issue ?

Comment: i wasnt able to change the color, but later i got the solution, i have added my solution that works for me

Comment: @ParthAnjaria your answer change all colorAccent of theme ! this answer works, i updated answer to know better

Comment: I placed this file in res/color. Also you can define `app:itemIconTint` for icons.

Answer (score 7):

If by dynamically you mean programmatically you could try this:

```
// FOR NAVIGATION VIEW ITEM TEXT COLOR
int[][] states = new int[][]{
        new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_checked},  // unchecked
        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked},   // checked
        new int[]{}                                // default
};

// Fill in color corresponding to state defined in state
int[] colors = new int[]{
        Color.parseColor("#747474"),
        Color.parseColor("#007f42"),
        Color.parseColor("#747474"),
};

ColorStateList navigationViewColorStateList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);

// apply to text color
navigationView.setItemTextColor(navigationViewColorStateList);

// apply to icon color
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(navigationViewColorStateList);
```

So you could define multiple colors for different settings like Day or Night.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that programmatically using

`MenuItemCompat.setIconTintMode(item, PorterDuff.Mode.DST)`

where `item` is a MenuItem you do not need a tint for.

Comment: This is the perfect solution! Please upvote as this should not be here at the bottom!

Comment: But this required at least API levels >= 26

Comment: @Ajay no. It works in my API 21+ project

Answer (score 0):

Finllay i got the answer,

You must change the colorAccent in the colors file to which ever color you want :

```
  <color name="colorAccent">whichever color required</color>
```

This solution worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
           .
           .
           app:itemIconTint="@color/your_selector_file_name" // for Icon
        app:itemTextColor="@color/your_selector_file_name" // for text
/>
```

Adding to what @DAVOOD said. The below color selector worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <!-- This is used when the Navigation Item is checked -->
        <item android:color="@color/tenoBrandColor" android:state_pressed="true" />
        <!-- This is the default text color -->
        <item android:color="@color/textprimary" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a simpler option for the lazy ones out there.

**TL;DR:** Just create a new `style` with the `colorPrimary` being your desired color and then set the `NavigationView`'s `theme` to be this new `style`.

Just make a new `style` as:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar.NavigationView">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/myDesiredColor</item>
</style>
```

This `style` will automatically inherit from your base `theme` (on my case it was `AppTheme.NoActionBar`) and then you just have to set the `colorPrimary` with your desired color.

Then you just have to set the `NavigationView`'s `theme` as:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.NavigationView"
```

in:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_menu_test"
    app:menu="@menu/main_drawer"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.NavigationView" />
```