# Navigation Drawer Menu Not Showing Some Icons

Tags: android

[image]

That round icons was supposed to look like this
[image]

```
 <item
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/nav_settings"
        android:title="Contact Us" />

    <item
```

*Even default icon  ic_launcher is not shown.*
**I am using Design Support Library for Navigation Drawer**

Comment: I tried chris banes cheesemaster from github and i was able to have the `ic_launcher icon` in the drawer. The tinting of the icon is by default .

Comment: Why Can't I use Colorful icon here? @Raghunandan... I am Using .png

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967851/change-navigation-view-item-color-dynamicly-android

Comment: Thanks alot @Raghunandan for the help. But what if I want to use icon With Multiple Color Combination.

Comment: the whole icon is tinted with one color. No wonder it is as it is in the screen shot. You need to change your icon

Comment: I tried With Multiple icons, it works fine except in Navigation Menu.

Comment: You need to look at the material design guidelines. http://www.google.co.in/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html# and secondly design of icons http://www.google.co.in/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-product-icons

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83992/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-katwal-dipak).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the discussions in the comment section , it looks like you don't want the icons to be tinted. So just use

```
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Note : This is not in line with the material design guidelines. I would not recommend this

Comment: It works! For kotlin, use: navView.itemIconTintList = null