# Change color of Navigation Drawer Icon in Android Studio default template

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

The new default Navigation Drawer Activity template in Android Studio

[image]

defines its titles and icons in a menu file `activity_main_drawer` like this:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camara"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_emo_cool"
        android:title="Import" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
        ...
```

The first item in my example uses a red icon:

[image]

but when I run the app, the color of the icon remains black.I have tested this for blue, green, yellow and purple icons, but the result is the same.

[image]

I read somewhere that the toolbar should use `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar` and my app already uses this in the `styles.xml` file:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Initially I thought this had something to do with Android Studio's cache feature so I invalidated cache and restarted Android Studio with no luck.

Comment: try to  `app:itemIconTint="@android:color/blue"` to your `navigation View`

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967851/change-navigation-view-item-color-dynamicly-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967851/change-navigation-view-item-color-dynamicly-android)

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Based on @MD's comment, all I needed to do was add:

```
app:itemIconTint="@color/my_desired_colour"
```

to `NavigationView` (it is located in `activity_main.xml` layout file) The default tint is black but you can use an even darker shade of black by using `#000000`

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:itemIconTint="#000000"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Comment: thanks :) How would I go about having a tint set for all the icons but one. For one particular icon, i want the tint set to null (i.e.) one particular menu item icon appears in its full color in all states

Comment: You welcome...But am not sure how you can achieve this.Sorry

Comment: What about different colors for each item? Google Play has navigation with such items or they just use PNG for colored items and vector drawables for other items?

Comment: @user25 I don't know how that was accomplished, sorry.

Comment: You will find your `NavigationView` into **menu** folder then just put 
`app:itemIconTint="#000000"` 
Note: "#000000" **You can change whatever color you want**

Answer (score 53):

Create a new style:

```
<style name="DrawerIconStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@android:color/red</item>
</style>
```

and in your theme, add this line:

```
<item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerIconStyle</item>
```

Comment: This worked for me perfectly. I needed to change drawer icon (three bars and arrow) color and it allowed me to do the change in first go.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to set it dynamically you can use:

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer);

actionBarDrawerToggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
```

Answer (score 6):

I called this method `navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);` in the `onCreate` so that i can override the default color of the icon items in navigation drawer like this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_places);
    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
}
```

Then i changed the color of each icon in navigation drawer using this `android:iconTint="@color/metallic_blue"` in `activity_places_drawer.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/invite"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_people_orange_24dp"
        android:title="@string/menu_invite"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium" />
</group>
```

Hope this answer helps.

Answer (score 5):

Just use this code:

```
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Comment: Thank you! Now my icons are colorful again.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @ojonugwa ochalifu and @MD's comment,

You can achieve by writing `app:itemIconTint` but if you write this, the navigation drawers icon color will also be changed. The simple and easy solution that I found after lots of R&D is that you have define `<item name="colorControlNormal">#FFE730</item>` in theme of `AppBarLayout` or if you using `Toolbar` only without `AppBarLayout`, you can also write `<item name="colorControlNormal">#FFE730</item>` in theme or `popupTheme` of `Toolbar` in your xml.

This will also change the color of activity's back arrow as well.

Hope this helps you all who are facing this type of issue.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was having a style

```
 <style name="MyToolbarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
     <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonOverflowStyle</item>
     <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
 </style>
 <style name="ActionButtonOverflowStyle">
        <item name="android:color">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle">
        <item name="android:color">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

and have applied the theme to the Appbar layout, so programatically chaining color didn't work.

So, **try removing any styles that you applied**, in case you are not able to change the color of the icon and then try the above given solutions.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me for changing icon color from the menu xml file which you drag in the `app:menu` attribute of the `NavigationView` widget.

Use `app:iconTint` attribute to set the icon color.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/..."
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
        android:title="..."
        app:iconTint="#FFEB3B" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id//..."
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:title="..."
        app:iconTint="#FFEB3B" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id//..."
        android:icon="@drawable/logout"
        android:title="..."
        app:iconTint="#FFEB3B"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

add itmIconTint in navigation view

```
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/drawerbackgtound"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
    app:iconTint="#FFFFFF"
    app:itemIconTint="#FFFFFF"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my drawer menu icon color by doing this line of code:

```
actionBarDrawerToggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable()
                     .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
```

Answer (score -1):

You must change the colorAccent in the colors file to which ever color you want :

```
  <color name="colorAccent">whichever color required</color>
```

This solution worked for me