# Navigation drawer menu icon is not displayed correctly

Tags: android, menu, icons

I want to input my customized icon into the menu in navigation drawer. However, when I run the application it only display a shadow of icon. How do I show the image correctly?

[image]

Here is the xml file for menu activity_main_drawer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/recent_picture"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_recent"
            android:title="Import" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Slideshow" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Tools" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Here is the xml layout with the navigation view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

There is another drawables.xml files found in the values folder.

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item name="ic_recent_picture" type="drawable">@mipmap/ic_recent</item>
<item name="ic_menu_gallery" type="drawable">@drawable/ic_menu_gallery</item>
<item name="ic_menu_slideshow" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow</item>
<item name="ic_menu_manage" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage</item>
<item name="ic_menu_share" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_share</item>
<item name="ic_menu_send" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_send</item>
```

Comment: Try put the image into `drawable` folder

Comment: @cwfei, I have tried put the image into drawable folder but it returns the same error too..

Comment: Did you update the reference in your xml file to be `android:icon="@drawable/ic_recent"` when you moved the image to the drawable folder?

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan, yes I did. when I click on the @mipmap/ic_recent, it will direct me to the correct icon.

Comment: Just to clarify we want to try changing it from `@mipmap/ic_recent` to `@drawable/ic_recent` like your other icons and then make sure the ic_recent icon is in your `drawable` folder. Is that what you did?

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan, Apologise, i should have clarified. I have tried both way, @mipmap/ic_recent and @drawable/ic_recent. The ic_recent icon was in drawable folder and also in mipmap folder. but somehow the icon is not displayed. is it because of navigationview only can include standard icon?

Comment: That is what I was trying to figure out. According to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28065664/1435985) mipmaps should only be used for application icons.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan, I actually created this navigation drawer from the template in android studio. It seems like only work for icon in the library only ...i not sure why

Comment: What kind of an image is ic_recent (png)? Try replacing it with another image, maybe even a duplicate of one of the other ones shown in the drawer, just to see if that at least works.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan, it is a small png file with color. I have tried replaced with other images but it still the same..I saw there is a drawable.xml file included . I have put the code block into the post..

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan, it is working now! by removing the tintmode from navigationview using this code  
       navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

Comment: Glad to hear it! I have to say I've never had to remove the tintmode on a png before.

Answer (score 37):

It works now by removing the tint effect from icon by `setItemIconTintList(null)`. Put the line of code below under the `navigationView`.

```
 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
 navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: Thanks Michelletbs,  navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null); solved my problem.

Comment: Great solution, works very well. Seems to be backwards compatible, pre lollipop still works. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Another solution, but only for interchanging 2 colors is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967851/change-navigation-view-item-color-dynamicly-android.

Comment: Thanks @michelletbs

Comment: Thanks @michelletbs, this is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change to another image to see if it is displaying?

```
<item name="ic_recent_picture" type="drawable">@mipmap/ic_recent</item>
```

Path @mipmap contains correct image?

Comment: I have replaced with the image which has pre-generated from template, its working. android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery", but if i put my own customized image then its display the grey square.

Comment: Hi @Weverton Peron, it works now by enter this code to remove tint mode from icon. 
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

Answer (score 0):

if you still haven't solved the problem by removing the tint, you might want to move your resource file to drawable (use Poject View) instead of drawable-anydpi like I did