# action bar buttons not showing

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i cannot seem to make the icons appear on the action bar on top of the activity at my project, i am using the right namespace with the right extend and everything should be running be smoothly, this is the xml for the menu items and i have added the line "xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"" and it still doesn't work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_search_white_24dp"
    android:title="Search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item android:id="@+id/action_add"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_add_white_48dp"
    android:title="Add"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

this is the java code for the menu inflater

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Do you call the menu xml in your android activity?

Comment: yes i just updated my question to add the activity part

Comment: Is the menu showing, in other words is the drop down menu showing? `ifRoom` is a bit finicky, if you want the icons to show try switching the `showAsAction` value to `always`

Comment: yes when i click on the 3 dots the menu still works and everything is working perfectly fine, but the icons will never show, i even tried the value to always and still nothing

Comment: This might have to do with using mipmaps, try changing your icons to be in the drawable folder. See this question for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867315/navigation-drawer-menu-icon-is-not-displayed-correctly

Comment: i tried adding them to the drawable folder instead of the mipmap and still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution to my problem.
since i have been trying to use namespace

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

then i should use

```
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

instead of

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to inflate your menu using

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
```

When you call `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Also try to add order attribute in your xml

Comment: i already did that, i will update my post to add the java code for it