# Disable a color tint in NavigationView only for specified icons

Tags: android, android-navigationview

I need to disable a tint color for some icons in `NavigationView` because their color define category type. How can I do it?

Below picture shows my problem:

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Comment: @Wax have you found the solution yet? I need to use two colors to one item and the rest grey..

Comment: @sanjeev I don't remember already, honestly, but seems u can only prepare few ColorTintLists and set got each item manually (in code)

Comment: @Шах yeah we could do that.. but how do you set the default icon color for the selected one? are you telling me its not possible?

Comment: Also it wouldn't be possible to use multiple colors in ColorTintLists for a single checked item sadly right?

Comment: @sanjeev yeah, of course, u can set it as u want

Answer (score 20):

```
navview.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Good luck!

Comment: It disables color tint for all items

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Then you can use a selector like that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967851/change-navigation-view-item-color-dynamicly-android

Comment: My problem that I need to use tint not for all items, only for specified which doesn't define some category. `ColorTintList` applies to all items in `NavigationView`.

Comment: Did you tried to get your menu item programatically, and modify the item's tint?

Comment: I try to set `ColorTintList` in `null` in `NavigationView` and use `DrawableCompat` to tint icons when I create menu but it doesn't work. All my icons became a black.

Answer (score 6):

If you want change color of icon on seletion the below is the possible answer:

[Change Navigation View Item Color Dynamicly Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967851/change-navigation-view-item-color-dynamicly-android)

Otherwise you can set

`navview.setItemIconTintList(null);`

this will give the original colors of icons. and you can use colored and grey icons as per your requirements.

Comment: I need different color state lists for different items

Comment: And I don't know how make it.

Comment: like on selection and deselection ?

Comment: Now, I'll post a picture to it be understandable (Don't know how to say in English)

Answer (score 3):

In case this is still relevant for somebody, we found a solution for a similar issue recently.

Although it is not possible (at least on API levels < 26) to set a custom tint list on individual items, you can set the tint mode individually. This worked for us:

```
val itemsWithoutTint: List<Int> = listOf(12345)
for (i in 0 until getMenu().size()) {
    val item = getMenu().getItem(i)
    if (item.itemId in itemsWithoutTint) {
        MenuItemCompat.setIconTintMode(item, PorterDuff.Mode.DST)
    }
}
```

By setting the TintMode to DST (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode), the source (in this case the tint color) is ignored and the destination (the icon to be tinted) is left untouched.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are using Kotlin, That's how it is done

```
val bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomnavigationhome)

// * THIS ONE 
bottomNavigationView.itemIconTintList = null
```

Answer (score -3):

```
 Menu menuNav = navigationView.getMenu();
 MenuItem menuItem = menuNav.findItem(R.id.nav_subjects);

 // Disable a tint color
 menuItem.setChecked(false);
```

I hope it answers your question.